# Hardware RAID1 device is the wrong size/too small?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, raid, lvm

My motherboard has an Intel RAID controller. I set up 2x3TB HDD in RAID1 named "Home". This should make a single device that is about 3TB. This is what I end up with:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003431e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     3905535     1951744   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         3907582   468860927   232476673    5  Extended
/dev/sda5         3907584   468860927   232476672   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00097a6c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00097a6c

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_djdcaefbcg_Home: 651.5 GB, 651543318528 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 79212 cylinders, total 1272545544 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00097a6c

              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

As you can see, I end up with a device that is 650GB, not 3TB. I'm using a fresh and updated install of Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in the RAID controller itself. I ended up giving up and going with software RAID instead.